# Am I understanding ご覧になって頂く／送らせて頂く correctly?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, politeness, keigo

Just for a little bit of context:  There's a flyer about a Japanese church's beach retreat that's been sent around, and I'm trying to translate it for practice.  That being said, the flyer has been attached to an e-mail, and some of the earlier stuff in the e-mail seemed to be talking about how a couple of the details about the beach retreat haven't been figured out quite yet.

Take the following sentence:

> でもリトリートがどんなものかは、スケジュールをご覧になって頂くと、一番分かると思いましたので、未完成ながらも送らせて頂きました。

I'm having a little bit of difficulty with this.  I've put together what I'm hoping is at least kind of close to what's being said:

> However as for a lot of the retreat's details, since I saw the schedule, and since I figured it had all the important stuff on there, it's going ahead and being sent around, despite not quite being finished just yet.

I know that some of the wording style is my own, but if I really knew how to translate the above, I wouldn't have affected the wording like that; this is largely to try to plug some holes in real quick while just practicing.

Also I noticed 頂く being used more than once; I know that the speaker generally wouldn't ever use it to refer to their own actions, but I really had no idea where it fit in.

What does the sentence above really say, and is there a pattern of difference between my translation and the real one?  Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

でもリトリートがどんなものかは、However as for what kind of thing the retreat is 
スケジュールをご覧になって頂くと、if you look at the schedule
一番分かると思いましたので、I thought you would best understand so
未完成ながらも while not complete
送らせて頂きました。I sent

> However I thought you would best understand what sort of retreat this is if you took a look at the schedule, so I went ahead and sent it though it's not finished yet.

ご覧になって頂く = ご覧になる (尊敬語 of 見る; listener's action) + 頂く(謙譲語 of もらう; speaker's action)
= (Literally) I receive(頂く) your looking(ご覧になる)
= Polite way of saying "you look"

送らせて頂きました = 送らせる (causative form of 送る) + 頂く
= (Literally) I received being allowed to send
= Polite way of saying "I sent it".
(This grammar is the topic of a question [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3260/what-would-be-the-literal-meaning-of-the-causative-form-here-%E6%9A%B4%E9%A2%A8%E8%AD%A6%E5%A0%B1%E7%99%BA%E4%BB%A4%E4%B8%AD%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9F%E3%82%81%E6%9C%AC%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AE%E5%96%B6%E6%A5%AD%E3%81%AF%E3%81%8A%E4%BC%91))

Comment: いまさらDV入ってる。一年以上も前の回答に。で、どこが間違っていますか？